# Работать с введенными данными

Tags: java, android

Есть диалог, где пользователь должен вставлять ссылку.

данные вводятся в EditText

код диалога:

```
private void showAddVideoDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setTitle("Добавить видео");
    View viewInflated = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_layout_add_video, (ViewGroup) getView(), false);
    final EditText input = (EditText) viewInflated.findViewById(R.id.edt_videoUrl);

    builder.setView(viewInflated);

    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ОК", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String string = input.getText().toString();
            onUserInput(string);
            getYouTubeId("https://");
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Отмена", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

После чего вызываем метод onUserInput, в котором начинаем *работать* со строкой:

```
private void onUserInput(String input){
    String placeholder = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/%s/0.jpg";
    String url = input.format(placeholder, id);
}
```

Проблема в том, что при попытке передать переменную в метод getYouTubeId, *url* которую мы объявили в onUserInput не используется(не передаётся)

```
private String getYouTubeId (String url) {
    String pattern = "(?<=youtu.be/|watch\\?v=|/videos/|embed\\/)[^#\\&\\?]*";
    Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(url);
    if(matcher.find()){
        return matcher.group();
    } else {
        return "error";
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как откорректировать метод

Comment: зависит от того, как вы показываете диалог.

Comment: @metalurgus обновил вопрос

Comment: Как вызывается этот диалог и куда нужно передать значение из EditText?

Comment: @pavlofff диалог вызывается посредством интерфейса public void clickVideo(int pos, View v) {
                showAddVideoDialog();
            }
а значение к примеру в метод какой то к примеру.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объявите в `Activity`( или `Fragment`, в зависимости от того, где вы вызываете метод `showAddVideoDialog`) метод:

```
void onUserInput(String input) {
    //тут делайте со строкой что угодно, сохраните в переменную, например
}
```

И измените ваш код так:

```
builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ОК", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // добавить следующее
        String string = input.getText().toString();
        onUserInput(string);
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, но вопрос заключался в том чтобы узнать КАК можно сохранить переменную в строке в Вашем методе onUserInput

Comment: @Inkognito, объявите переменную с именем например `peremennaya`, и напишите `peremennaya = input`. Я думал, что это очевидно

Comment: getText выделяет ошибкой - Cannot resolve method(

Comment: @Inkognito, ну, и дальше что? Где остальная часть?

Comment: в смысле? в строке String string = input.getText.toString();  - getText подчеркивает красным с ошибкой что нельзя реализовать данный метод, больше никаких дополнений.

Comment: @Inkognito, вы дали только кусок полного текста ошибки `Cannot resolve method(`

Comment: это всё что пишет, откуда мне взять вам еще? если эта ошибка возникла даже не при запуске программы.

Comment: @Inkognito, покажите скриншот

Comment: @Inkognito скобки надо поставить после getText :) - input.getText().toString();

Comment: @pavlofff, да, точно. Я ж на коленке писал.

Comment: после getText  поставьте (), должно заработать)

Comment: @metalurgus Супер, и еще последний момент(вторая часть вопроса) почему я когда в другом методе прописываю значение peremennaya как было условленно выше, он всё равно в методе onUserInput пишет что нигде данная переменная не используется, хотя все это у меня находится в одном фрагменте.

Comment: @Inkognito,  все зависит от того, как вы это делаете.

Comment: @Inkognito, добавьте в вопрос новый код, покажите, как именно вы используете  переменную, или задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: @Inkognito http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46240/

Comment: @Inkognito Объявите свою переменную `peremennaya` полем класса и она будет доступна везде в пределах фрагмента.